# How to import array lists from one activity to another in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

I am basically creating a program in which one class has data from a wardrobe, basically three array lists consisting of tops bottoms and footwear, if the user selects the generate button it automatically takes them to the generate screen. How would I call the array lists in the activity that it is going to (generate screen)?

Here is what I have in the activity before the generate screen :

```
private ArrayList top = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList bot = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList fw = new ArrayList();

a = new Intent(this, Generator.class);

a.putStringArrayListExtra("Tops", top);
a.putStringArrayListExtra("Bottoms", bot);
a.putStringArrayListExtra("Footwear", fw);
startActivity(a);
```

How would I return those values in the generator class to be used in their?

Answer (score 0):

In your Generator class in onCreate

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> top = i.getStringArrayListExtra("Tops");
ArrayList<String> bot = i.getStringArrayListExtra("Bottoms");
ArrayList<String> fw = i.getStringArrayListExtra("Footwear");
```

Comment: i keep on getting errors for the three arrays i put in saying do something like this saying change top to string[]

Comment: I mean to write getStringArrayListExtra.

Comment: in your generate class you would put :  Intent i = getIntent();
  
  top =i.getStringExtra("top");
  bottom = i.getStringExtra("bottom");
  fw = i.getStringExtra("fw");

Comment: But top is an an ArrayList as you define it, and you put it as a.putStringArrayListExtra("Tops", top); so to get it you have to use my code. If you mean top is only a String than it is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

in your generate class you would put

Intent i = getIntent();

```
    top =i.getStringExtra("top");
    bottom = i.getStringExtra("bottom");
    fw = i.getStringExtra("fw");
```